# Error: code too large

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Tengo el siguiente `arraylist`: [Polylines](http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1498267740292.txt),el `arraylist` tiene 190 elementos, el cual al compilar me genera el siguiente error:

> error: code too large

Según lo que investigue es un error de java, pero no sé como solucionarlo, espero puedan ayudarme

**edit:**

Aquí dejo la clase:

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        ArrayList<FormatoPolyline> Poly=new ArrayList<>();
        String previus;
        Polyline line;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            previus="";

        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            int height = 50;
            int width = 50;
            BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
            Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
            Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
            marcadores(mMap,smallMarker);


            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-33.502482,-70.573841), 15f));


            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    Polylines(mMap,marker.getTitle());
                    return false;
                }
            });
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    if(line!=null) {
                        line.remove();
                        line=null;
                        Log.d("Polyline","no es nula");
                    }else {
                        Log.d("Polyline","es nula");
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        public int getRandomColor(){
            Random rnd = new Random();
            return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        }

        public void Polylines(GoogleMap map, String ruta){
            lineas();
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            if(line!=null) {
                line.remove();
                line=null;
                Log.d("Polyline","no es nula");
            }

            for(int i=0;i<Poly.size();i++){
                polylineOptions=null;
                if (Poly.get(i).getTitulo().equals(ruta)){
                    polylineOptions=Poly.get(i).getLine();
                    break;
                }
            }

            polylineOptions.width(8).color(getRandomColor()).geodesic(true).clickable(false);
            line = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

            Log.d("puntos",""+line.getPoints());
            Log.d("tamaño",""+line.getPoints().size());
        }

        public void lineas(){

// aqui va el arraylist, el link esta en la pregunta, no puedo publicar una pregunta con tanto texto
     }


        public void marcadores(GoogleMap map, Bitmap smallMarker){
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.510449,-70.742893)).title("5 de Abril / Esquina Blanca").snippet("Vereda y bandejón / Bidireccional / Primera Transversal a Concepción del Oro ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.472688,-70.72111)).title("5 de Abril / Parque por Simón Bolívar").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Vostok a Las Torres ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.460697,-70.716328)).title("Alameda / Pajaritos").snippet("Bandejón y Calle / Bidireccional / Teatinos a Escr. Jorge Inostroza ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.516518,-70.755622)).title("Alberto Llona").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Vicente Reyes a 5 de Abril ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.457891,-70.669612)).title("Almirante Blanco Encalada").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Club Hípico a San Alfonso ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.6148516,-70.6874084)).title("Almirante Riveros").snippet("Bandejón y Vereda / Bidireccional / Padre Hurtado a Portales oriente").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.4405378,-70.5177802)).title("Alvaro Casanova").snippet("Vía Ciclística (Calle) / Bidireccional / Valenzuela Pulema a Alcalde Fernando Castillo Velasco ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.442017,-70.612768)).title("Antonio Varas").snippet("Calle y Vereda / Bidireccional / Nueva Providencia a Irarrázaval ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.411492,-70.630575)).title("Arzobispo Valdivieso").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Comandante Véliz a Ocho Norte ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.5825107,-70.6341505)).title("Baldomero Lillo").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Aníbal Pinto a Andrés Bello").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.603182,-70.7019353)).title("Barros Arana").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Ramón Liborio a Esmeralda ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.346124,-70.728705)).title("Bernardo OHiggins").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Colbún a San Ignacio ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.43618,-70.664602)).title("Brasil").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Huérfanos a Mapocho ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.625698,-70.780365)).title("Calera De Tango / Manuel Castillo").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Los Almendros a Autopista Del Sol ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.558337,-70.615721)).title("Callao").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Alcántara a Sánchez Fontecilla ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.6003962,-70.7806125)).title("Calle 2").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Camino a Lonquén a Calle 2 ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.41897,-70.596611)).title("Calle G").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Juan Cristóbal a Juan Muñoz ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.6404369,-70.8165622)).title("Camino a Lonquén").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Fuente Bella a Carampangue ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.377763,-70.655048)).title("Camino a Melipilla / Pedro Aguirre Cerda").snippet("Calle y vereda / Bidireccional / Avenida Cuatro a Esquina Blanca ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.4133171,-70.846045)).title("Camino a Noviciado").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Ruta 68 a Puente El Noviciado ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.6238216,-70.7570601)).title("Camino Catemito (a)").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Calera De Tango a San Agustín ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.6086507,-70.7206249)).title("Camino Catemito (b)").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Pdte. Jorge Alessandri Rodríguez a Universidad Santo Tomás ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.6025744,-70.7810068)).title("Camino El Tanguito").snippet("Camino a Lonquén a Calle 2 ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.502332,-70.710687)).title("Cardenal Raúl Silva Henríquez").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Jorge Quevedo a San Gregorio ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.540047,-70.620863)).title("Cardenal Raúl Silva Henríquez / Américo Vespucio").snippet("Vereda, Calle y Bandejón / Bidireccional / Canal Torrente a Porvenir ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.4206649,-70.6697112)).title("Carlos Medina / Soberanía").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Pdte Edurado Frei Montalva a Domingo Santa María ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.4776212,-70.6421864)).title("Carlos Silva Vildosola / Santa Rosa ").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / San Diego a Locarno ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.484084,-70.63058)).title("Carlos Valdovinos").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Santa Rosa a Vicuña Mackenna ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.474207,-70.6351)).title("Carmen / Las Industrias").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / General Jofré a Comercio ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.47574,-70.6684)).title("Centenario (a)").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Club Hípico a Bascuñán Guerrero ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.476516,-70.6540203)).title("Centenario (b)").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / San Ignacio a Nataniel Cox ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.4764936,-70.6464887)).title("Centenario (c)").snippet("Vereda y Bandejón / Bidireccional / San Diego a Santa Rosa ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.515617,-70.693722)).title("Central Cardenal Silva Henríquez").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Buenaventura a Américo Vespucio ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.378249,-70.5032533)).title("Charles Hamilton").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / San José de la Sierra a Fray Montalva ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.450696,-70.598056)).title("Chile España").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Simón Bolívar a Miguel de Cervantes ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.4267047,-70.6190336)).title("Cirujano Guzmán").snippet("Calle / Norte a Sur / Pérez Valenzuela a Providencia").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.493925,-70.676427)).title("Clotario Blest").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Carlos Valdovinos a Lo Ovalle ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.462861,-70.664945)).title("Club Hípico").snippet("Vereda / Norte a Sur / Grajales a Pedro Montt ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.588785,-70.7079756)).title("Colón").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Freire a Patria Nueva ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.4098781,-70.7016993)).title("Costanera Sur").snippet("Vereda y Bandejón / Bidireccional / Santos Luis Medel a Pdte. Balmaceda ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.609573,-70.602758)).title("Cuatro Oriente / Caletera Acceso Sur (a)").snippet("Vereda y Calle / Bidireccional / Sargento Menadier a Primavera ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.632777,-70.611025)).title("Cuatro Oriente / Caletera Acceso Sur (b)").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Cerro Yaretas a Camino El Retiro ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.446171,-70.644541)).title("Curicó / Tarapacá / Padre Felipe Gómez de Vidaurre").snippet("Calle / Oriente a Poniente / Vicuña Mackenna a San Ignacio ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.50735,-70.62666)).title("Departamental (a)").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Vicuña Mackenna a Nueva Berlioz ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.51031,-70.587872)).title("Departamental (b)").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Tobalaba a Entrada Florida Center ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.393366,-70.655756)).title("Diagonal José María Caro").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / El Guanaco a Quebrada del Obispo ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.461932,-70.594078)).title("Doctor Johow").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Grecia a José Ignacio Vergara ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.396488,-70.6618416)).title("Dorsal / Roma").snippet("Vereda y Bandejón / Recoleta a Bajos de Jiménez ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.459932,-70.574753)).title("Dublé Almeyda").snippet("Vereda / Poniente a Oriente / Los Corteses a Exequiel Figueroa ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.4442263,-70.560658)).title("Echeñique").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Tobalaba a Vicente Pérez Rosales ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.401914,-70.629014)).title("Einstein / Las Torres").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Antonia Prado a Los Zapadores ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.6410041,-70.7339984)).title("El Barrancón").snippet("Vereda / Norte a Sur / Camino Calera De Tango a Santa Inés ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.589223,-70.800941)).title("El Copihue").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Los Nogales a Camino a Lonquén ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.502482,-70.573841)).title("Los Cerezos").snippet("Los Cerezos").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Podrias colocar parte de tu codigo donde cargas el array? Por metodo hay un maximo de 64KB de bytecode, puede que sea ese tu problema http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4309152

Comment: @mmartinez7 publique la clase completa

Comment: Probablemente el metodo marcadores supere los 64KB (eso puedes comprobarlo quitando parte del codigo y viendo si vuelves al mismo error). La solución rápida si realmente necesitas mantener en ese momento todos esos marcadores es particionar el metodo en sub-metodos para no pasar esa limitación de Java. No sé si existe una solución mejor, a priori me suena bastante poco óptima pero es comunmente aceptada.

Comment: quite los marcadores y no fueron el problema, sigue marcandome el metodo del arraylist

Comment: Perdón, pense que tu comentario en el codigo referia al metodo marcar..Recien ahora veo el link en tu pregunta. Realmente tienes que tener en memoria toda esa informacion? No puedes pedir a demanda desde un archivo/bdd? Puedes probar tambien particionar la inicializacion del array.

Comment: estuve investigando y lo mejor es obtenerlo desde un archivo, pero no tengo idea como realizarlo y por ende publique la pregunta y ver si existia otra solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione creando 2 metodos los cuales rellenaran el arraylist, y me retornaran una variable de tipo arraylist, los 2 metodos rellenan mi arraylist axuliar y con eso pude seguir normal

Answer (score 2):

En vez de colocar todos los datos para popular tu `ArrayList` en el código de tu clase, considera ponerlos en un areglo de `String`en los recursos.

**¡Recuerda!: XML es como la violencia - si no soluciona tu problema, no lo usaste suficientemente consecuente.**

Crea dentro de `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="coordinates">
        <item>IV Centenario (a),-33.510449,-70.742893,-33.409332,-70.564671,-33.416716,-70.554494,-33.413263,-70.559207</item>
        <item>5 de Abril / Esquina Blanca,-33.510661,-70.753157,-33.510645,-70.75172,-33.51063,-70.750301,-33.510598,-70.74892200000001,-33.510583,-70.747423,-33.51054,-70.746028,-33.510516,-70.744617,-33.510478000000006,-70.743815,-33.510449,-70.742893,-33.51035,-70.741265,-33.510339,-70.740253,-33.510366,-70.739881,-33.510621,-70.739894,-33.510699,-70.739089,-33.510793,-70.73800000000001,-33.510889,-70.737059,-33.510992,-70.735922,-33.51099,-70.735922,-33.510997,-70.735919</item>
            ...   
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Luego puedes popular tu arreglo:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] puntos = res.getStringArray(R.array.coordinates);

for (String punto : puntos){
    String[] data = punto.split(",");
    String nombre = data[0];
    LongLat[] ll = new LatLng[data.length/2]; // cantidad de tuples
    for (int i = 0; i<ll.length; i++){
        ll[i] = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(data[1+i*2]),
                Double.parseDouble(data[2+i*2]));
    }
    Poly.add(new FormatoPolyline(nombre,
            new PolylineOptions().add(ll)));
}
```

**¡Importante!** Asegúrate que el texto no contiene `,` o elige otro separador (que no esta dentro de los caracteres permitidos en el texto. Ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="coordinates">
        <item>IV Centenario (a);-33.510449;-70.742893;-33.409332;-70.564671;-33.416716;-70.554494;-33.413263;-70.559207</item>
        <item>5 de Abril / Esquina Blanca;-33.510661;-70.753157;-33.510645;-70.75172;-33.51063;-70.750301;-33.510598;-70.74892200000001;-33.510583;-70.747423;-33.51054;-70.746028;-33.510516;-70.744617;-33.510478000000006;-70.743815;-33.510449;-70.742893;-33.51035;-70.741265;-33.510339;-70.740253;-33.510366;-70.739881;-33.510621;-70.739894;-33.510699;-70.739089;-33.510793;-70.73800000000001;-33.510889;-70.737059;-33.510992;-70.735922;-33.51099;-70.735922;-33.510997;-70.735919</item>
            ...   
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Populando tu arreglo con::

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] puntos = res.getStringArray(R.array.coordinates);

for (String punto : puntos){
    String[] data = punto.split(";");
    String nombre = data[0];
    LongLat[] ll = new LatLng[data.length/2]; // cantidad de tuples
    for (int i = 0; i<ll.length; i++){
        ll[i] = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(data[1+i*2]),
                Double.parseDouble(data[2+i*2]));
    }
    Poly.add(new FormatoPolyline(nombre,
            new PolylineOptions().add(ll)));
}
```

Comment: no creo que usar algun tipo de base datos sea lo mejor, hay indices que contienen mas Puntos que entras por ende existen variaciones de puntos en cada indice

Comment: Ya me di cuenta que la cantidad de puntos son variables. te cambié el código a una alternativa sin SQLite usando los recursos.